# Determine App Server type from Spring?

Tags: java, spring, appserver

I would like to print (as debug info) the type and version of the App Server my webapp is running on.

With a little search so far I was able to come up with this via the `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`:

`this.environment.getProperty("java.naming.factory.initial")`

However it just says `"org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory"` and not like `"Apache Tomcat/8.0.33"` which I would like to see.

Comment: Does your application always run on Tomcat and you just want to print its version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ServletContext.getServerInfo()`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServerInfo())

*Btw: In Spring you can inject `ServletContext`*

```
@Service
public class ServerLoggingService() {

  @Autowired
  private ServletContext servletContext;

  @PostConstruct
  public void printServer() {
      System.out.println("Server Version: " + this.servletContext.getServerInfo());
  }
}
```

Comment: In some places you can inject servlet context, but not in others.